# How do you get multiple elements to disappear when you click on it?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am doing a Vanilla JS practice and I'd like to remove a div whenever I click on a span saying"continue". However, I got stuck at the JS coding.

EACH DIV HAS THE CLASSES one, two and three respectively.

here's my code

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p class="card" id="test"><span class="texta">Hello<br><span class="next">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
     <div class="two">
    <p class="card" id="test"><span class="texta">Hello<br><span class="next">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
     <div class="three">
    <p class="card"><span class="texta">Hello<br><span class="next" onClick="move()">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function move(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("three")[0].style="opacity:0";
}
```

I'm trying to do the effect using as much JS as possible, and as little html as possible. Apart from coding each and every div by getElementsByClassName(""), is there a more efficient way to go about it?
Also, I thought I saw event.target syntax somewhere online before and I wonder if it could be applied in this context?

Thanks for any help rendered!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more dynamic solution. Also in your HTML-Code are some mistakes (missing '/' in an ending span; identical id's).

```js
function move(el) {
    el.closest('div').style = 'display: none;'
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="one">
      <p class="card">
        <span class="texta">Hello<br>
          <span class="next" onClick="move(this)">Continue</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <p class="card">
        <span class="texta">Hello<br>
          <span class="next" onClick="move(this)">Continue</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <p class="card">
        <span class="texta">Hello<br>
          <span class="next" onClick="move(this)">Continue</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function move(className){
 document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].style="display:none";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <p class="card" id="test"><span class="texta">Hello1<br><span class="next" onClick="move('one')">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
     <div class="two">
    <p class="card" id="test"><span class="texta">Hello2<br><span class="next" onClick="move('two')">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
     <div class="three">
    <p class="card"><span class="texta">Hello3<br><span class="next" onClick="move('three')">Continue</span><span></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can you please check you want this type of thing or not?